# JFrame - Icon not showing on Sys tray when JFrame has been minimised

Tags: java, swing, icons, jframe, system-tray

I'm currently dealing with minimizing a JFrame to the system tray and I've done so successfully as indicated below:

```
    // 
    URL resource = panel.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("boston.png");
    System.out.println("rfc95Panel.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource() is: " + rfc95Panel.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("boston.png"));

    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(resource);

    //
    frame.setIconImage(image);

    // 
    if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
        final TrayIcon icon = new TrayIcon(image);
        icon.setToolTip("Program minimised");

        // 
        icon.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setExtendedState(frame.NORMAL);
                getSystemTray().remove(icon);
            }
        });

        // Adds the specified window state listener to receive window events 
        // from this window. If l is null, no exception is thrown and no action 
        // is performed.
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
                try {
                    getSystemTray().add(icon);
                } catch (AWTException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The problem is when minimised I can't see the image/icon when I open the system tray i.e. I can see the tool tip but I can't see the icon related to my program - see image below

[image: sys tray image]

Any ideas as to what I'm missing? I feel it might be something basic.

Comment: Are you sure that your bosten.png file is being correctly loaded?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Hi Grammin, thanks for the reply .. the image loads correctly .. i can confirm this by printing the image location on the console which is rfc95Panel.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource() is: file:/C:/Users/TestProject/bin/boston.png .. i can also see the image on the taskbar when the program is open ..

Comment: Any ideas anyone? I appreciate any assistance

Comment: `Any ideas anyone?` - see Andrew's comment.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: The icon is 64 by 64. Is there a specific set of dimensions for sys tray icons? thanks.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: thanks your question lead me to the answer. I reduced the icon size and it appeared in the system tray.

Comment: There is an option (somewhere in the TrayIcon API) to auto resize the icon, but I tend not to use it as its not very good ;)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to the above problem I was encountering was the size of the image I intended to use as the sys tray icon. Basically my dimensions were 64 by 64 but ideally it should be that the dimensions are smaller in my case I reduced the image to 16 by 16.